# How to change shape ggplot2 using jitter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot doesn't let me change the shapes in the plot.
I used the mtcars dataset for this example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color=cyl)) +
geom_jitter(shape = mtcars$vs, width = 0.25, alpha = 0.5) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 13))
```

This gives me the following output:
[image]

The shapes aren't changed in the shapes that I have entered (1 and 13).
How do I get this done?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Put `shape = vs` within `aes`, just like color. Voting to close as typo

Comment: Thanks. Adjusted the script and added your suggestion. It works now.